# JwtSecurityToken expiration date is two hours apart

Tags: api, jwt

In my .net core api application, I use:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60); // time is 2018-04-27 14:49:00

var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

var claims = new[]
              {
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)
              };

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        _config["Tokens:Issuer"], 
        _config["Tokens:Audience"], 
        claims,
        expires: dt,
        signingCredentials: creds);
```

`token.ValidTo` is shown as `2018-04-27 12:49:00` ...

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the different timezones. Your timezone is probably UTC+2, and your variable `dt` contains the time in local time.

But [`JwtSecurityToken.ValidTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytoken.validto.aspx) is a `DateTime` value which contains a time in UTC. The resulting JWT will give you a value [(`exp` claim)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058353/how-jwt-token-expiresin-works-in-feathers/42063121#42063121) based in Unix Epoch Time in seconds sine 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC. 
In your case `exp` will be

> 1524833340

which equals

> 2018-04-27 12:49:00 UTC (14:49 in UTC+2)

as you can check [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) and the JWT framework knows how to handle that, independent from the timezone.

The behaviour is correct and you don't need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

In server side create token method, use Utc time to generate expiration time:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(tokenValidityInMinutes),
            claims: authClaims,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );
```

and in client side check for Utc time :

```
var identity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenDTO?.Token) || tokenDTO?.Expiration < DateTime.UtcNow
```

In fact local time makes this problem, so you need to create an expiration time based on Utc and check it with DateTime.UtcNow