# JWT expire. Which method is best?

Tags: php, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am trying to find away to have the JWT expire I have it generated should I use "exp" attribute or write an if statement with /DateTime object? I am new to PHP.

I have tried the \DateTime object but is it redundant? Maybe I need a better understanding of how the expire attribute works within the token.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
$jwt_key = $client->getClientSecret();
$user_id = $client->getClientId();
$client_id = $client->getId();
$grant_types ='Null'; 
$token_data = array(
'client Id; => $user_id,
'Client Secret' => $jwwt_ket,
'Id' => $client)id,
'Grant Types' => $grant_types
);
$token_string = JWT::encode($token_data, $jwt_key);
$token = new Token($client);
$token->setAccessToken($token_string);
return $token_string;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"I have tried the \DateTime object but is it redundant"_? Also, how to set the expire date on JWT is shown in almost every JWT guide I've seen. If you're having some issue with your code, you need to show us the code and explain what the actual issue is. Right now, your question is very unclear.

Comment: Have you tried looking up what each of them done on php.net?

Comment: I have looked at the JWT guidelines for conventional attributes. So I guess what im asking in PHP should i set the token to expire through a if statement or is that all done within the structure of the JWT and library

Comment: If you're using `Firebase\JWT\JWT`, just use `exp`. The library will automatically handle it and throw a handy exception if the token has expired, with no logic required on your end.

Answer (score 1):

`exp` defines the time at which the token expires (expressed in UNIX epoch time (seconds since 01.01.1970 00:00)).
As part of the token validation, the framework will check `exp`and consider the token invalid/expired, when it was received after exp.

It's the recommended standard way and you don't have to implement anything extra with DateTime objects.

More details about how exp is defined can be found in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058353/how-jwt-token-expiresin-works-in-feathers/42063121#42063121)

Comment: So assuming I use the standard way using the expire attribute that has the time in the token its self how do i keep track of it on my end?

Comment: some frameworks send an extra field along with the token, telling you when the token expires. If not, you can decode the token on client side and extract the exp. The payload is just bas64url encoded.

Comment: In your experience wheres the best place to store a JWT?

Comment: That's a quite frequent question for which you can find good and detailed answers here on SO. I'm not a frontend developer.